# How do submit form information to my MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Edit 4: The main issue has been resolved - turned out the problem was a couple of my typos. (Post, <) Thank you! The data now gets entered into my database ok. I'll still consider the other tips you are giving me. Very good first experience with stackoverflow.

Edit 1: OK, I forgot to capitalize $_POST. Now I am getting an error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
Edit 2: I removed `ID` and added exit();. Now, I have the error message "Column 'Name' cannot be null". I am not sure how/where to add the escape string.
  Edit 3: I am following Damien's instructions, and I have this as my output: "Connected to MySQL 
string(8) "TestName" string(16) "Test Description" string(3) "567" string(6) "234567" string(13) "Test@test.com" string(8) "TestPass" Column 'Name' cannot be null" - so still the same error.

Original Question:
I am rather new to using MySQL and PHP. I am using MAMP for my server, and have set up a few PHP files, according to instructions I have been given. Right now, the main goal is to be able to set up a user database, and the form in question should create a new user, with username, password, etc.

When I have filled out the form and press submit, it gives the error message for an incomplete form, instead of sending the data like I want it too. (I am not really sure about how sending data to my database works, either.)

Here is the form (I think it's in HTML):

```
<form action="create.php" method="post">
 Name:  <input type="text" name="inputName" value="" /><br>
 Description: <input type="text" name="inputDesc" value=""/>
  <br/>
 Phone Number :  (<input type="text" name="inputPArea" value="" />)
- <input type="text" name ="inputPBody" value="" /><br>
 Email: <input type="text" name="inputEmail" value=""/><br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="inputPass" value=""/>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

Here is the if/else statement for the error message:

```
if(!$_Post['submit']){
    echo "please fill out the form";
    header('Location:demo.php');

    }

else {
     mysql_query( "INSERT INTO people (`ID`,`Name`,`Description`,`Area Code`,`Phone Body`,`Email`,`Password`)
               VALUES(NULL<'$name','$desc','$area','$pbody','$email','$pass') ") or die(mysql_error()) ;

echo "User has been added!";
header('Location: demo.php');

     }
```

Please help! Thank you. It would be nice if you could help me understand how submitting stuff to my database works.

(There is a lot of other PHP stuff, of course. Tell me if you need any of it.)

Comment: You have the right idea - just make sure it's $_POST and to check, use if (isset($_POST['submit']) And don't forget the get the values of all your inputs too - from your $_POST superglobal. You have to extract them from that first (I recommened using mysql_real_escape_string() on them before assigning them to variable that you put into a query. I'd suggest prepared statements, but you should master this concept first.

Comment: Lots of concerns here...

Comment: Thank you kinakuta - I feel silly now.

Comment: Now I have an error message: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: I don't understand most of what kinakuta is saying...

Comment: Sorry, I should have put it in an answer instead of a comment. See @Damien's answer.

Comment: You have a "<" char between NULL and '$name'; I suspect that's causing "column count doesn't match value count" error - try a comma instead.  Also, you should really check the return value of mysql_query to be sure it succeeds, or else you'll be telling the user they've been added even when they possibly haven't!

Comment: Thank you Nick Shaw, another dumb typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputName']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputDesc']);
$area = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPArea']);
$pbody= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPBody']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputEmail']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPass']);
```

You access them through the superglobal $_POST array (since you used 'post' as the form method), properly sanitized (you should use PDO and **prepared statements** though, they'll make your code even safer). ID, if it is set as Auto Increment, is not needed in your query.

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO people (`Name`,`Description`,`Area Code`,`Phone Body`,`Email`,`Password`) VALUES('$name','$desc','$area','$pbody','$email','$pass') ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Suggestions:
Also, consider adding **exit();** after your header redirection, to avoid accidental display of the code.

 You should also check if $_POSTs are set `if(isset($_POST['postname']))` if you don't want (or can't accept) empty values (even if you're doing a client-side validation for that. Always rely on server-side validation, as client-side can be easily avoided)

Warning on mysql_real_escape_string:

> A MySQL connection is required before
>   using mysql_real_escape_string()
>   otherwise an error of level E_WARNING
>   is generated, and FALSE is returned.
>   If link_identifier isn't defined, the
>   last MySQL connection is used.

Comment: I have removed 'ID', and added exit();. Now I get the error message: "Column 'Name' cannot be null"

Comment: I'm not really sure where to put the escape thing. Should I replace my existing "$name = $_POST['inputName'];" etc. ?

Comment: @Xheia..well, is it empty? do a var_dump($var) for each of your vars to see if they actually contain something...and check your code, sometimes it's just a wrong-spelled word here or there.. Oh, yes, you _definitely_ should escape. After you connect to the DB, escape, and then query

Comment: @Xheia: mysql_real_escape_string needs a connection in order to work. Be sure to connect to the db before using it. I updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't see that you removed the " Null< " as well as the `ID` - that was another of my typos.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Should I put the if(isset($_POST['postname'])) before the entire if/else statement?

Comment: if you want to check for it not being empty, you could do `if(isset($_POST['inputName'])) { $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputName']); }`, and the same for the others. But it's up to you, was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement, add:

```
$name = $_POST['inputName'];
$desc = $_POST['inputDesc'];
$pbody = $_POST['inputPBody'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$pass = $_POST['inputPass'];
```

Consider [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @Xheia: split your query line into 2 parts: `$sql = "INSERT ..."; mysql_query($sql) or die('query: ' . $sql . '//' . mysql_error());`. This way you have the generated query in a string which you can output to check for errors. Separating them like this is VERY handy for debugging.

Comment: I only somewhat understand Marc B. - I don't think I'll do this right now, but I'll consider it if I need more debugging.